# Can we implement Github workflow which runs always?

Tags: github, github-actions

Is there straight way how to make GitHub action run on any event

**e.g.**

```yaml
name: always
on: *

jobs:
  run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: "echo \"this job runs on any event...\""
```

Want to send from custom action notification on any event occurring in the repo!

Comment: I don't think there's a way around listing all events explicitly, but I'm curious what the use case for this would be?

Comment: @BenjaminW.To send via custom action notification to any API One wants that some event occurred in the repo.

Comment: I recommend setting up a webhook for the repo (Settings > Webhook), that's exactly what they're designed for.

Comment: That's the point ... to replace separate micoservice using webhook with action instead. So that I don't need to have separated microserveice handling "Send me everything. ", but could run that inside the each repo dedicated action instead.